# Tuleap, how to see the project services provided by pluggins recently installed and activated?

Tags: plugins, tuleap

I have installed **Tuleap** 8.6 on **centos 6**. Tuleap is working fine. Nevertheless the **new plugins** I have just installed **does not provide their project services**.

I have tried with the pluggins git, agiledashboard and hudson.
None of the services this pluggins provide are shown in the page *project/admin/servicebar.php?group_id=xxx*.

*I had the same problem with Tuleap 8.5 on an other machine. But the problem disappeared after the update process to Tuleap 8.6.*

So their might be an automatic process that takes places during tuleap upgrade that I miss to do when installing new pluggins.

To install the plugins:

1. I go to the page *plugins/pluginsadministration/* and I click on the plugin I want to *install*
2. I click *"Yes, I am sure"*
3. Then in *plugins/pluginsadministration/* I turned *"avaible?"* to *"yes"* on the line of the plugin.
4. The I have tried to restart the machine, etc... Nothing work:
   The pluggin service does not appear.

Does someone know how to fully install new pluggins in Tuleap in order to have access to the project services they provide??

Thanks.

Comment: Could you try to run on the server `tuleap --clear-caches` ?

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Manuel Vacelet who has solved my problem!

I write the full procedure to simplify the reading.

To fully install a plugin (install, activate, and activate plugins services)  in Tuleap on Centos, the procedure is:

1. go to the page plugins/pluginsadministration/ and I click on the plugin I want to install
2. click "Yes, I am sure";
3. Then in plugins/pluginsadministration/ I turned "avaible?" to "yes" on the line of the plugin.
4. **Execute tuleap --clear-caches** (then you might need to restart tuleap by executing *service tuleap restart*)

Comment: FYI, I didn't manage to reproduce this with master version of Tuleap. The code is designed to force the cache clear at plugin install